# jQuery Sortable and alert if condition matched

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I would like to issue an alert when the list has been sorted in certain orders.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="listHolder">
   <div class="order-1">item1</div>
   <div class="order-2">item2</div>
   <div class="order-3">item3</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
   $(".listHolder").sortable({
       axis: 'y',//constrains vertical movement
       update: function () { //triggered when sorting stopped

        var dataAuto = $(".listHolder").sortable("serialize", {
            key: " za",
            attribute: "class",
        });

        if (dataAuto == "za=3&za=2&za=1"||"za=2&za=1&za=3") {
            alert(dataAuto);
        }

     },
   });
```

At the moment, there is something wrong with the if statement. The `dataAuto` variable holds the [serialize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) values, and I want the alert to show if the list is sorted to either 3-2-1 or 2-1-3, and should match the string `"za=3&za=2&za=1"||"za=2&za=1&za=3"`.

If you remove the if statement you will see the string in the alert

```
    $(".listHolder").sortable({
       axis: 'y',//constrains vertical movement
       update: function () { //triggered when sorting stopped

        var dataAuto = $(".listHolder").sortable("serialize", {
            key: " za",
            attribute: "class",
        });

        alert(dataAuto);

     },
   });
```

See an example with the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YSF7q/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems

1. a space in the key `za`
2. your if conditions second part was a constant string `"za=2&za=1&za=3"` which would be truthy always

it should be

```
$(".listHolder").sortable({
    axis: 'y',//constrains vertical movement
    update: function () { //triggered when sorting stopped
        var dataAuto = $(".listHolder").sortable("serialize", {
            key: "za",
            attribute: "class",
        });

        if (dataAuto == "za=3&za=2&za=1" || dataAuto == "za=2&za=1&za=3") {
            alert(dataAuto);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EVvQn/)